# Country settings in Google Play

Tags: android, settings, google-play

Can someone please explain me these settings?

There's first "pricing" label. In the next line there's a checkbox with "All Countries" and then a list with checkboxes for certain contries. Then another checkbox with "Rest of the world, except for:" and again a list with countries, different from the ones in the first list.

Why is the list divided this way? Would not be 1 group enough (for example "all countries" and countries from country list)? I mean this is very redundant, and confusing, if I select e.g. in the first list a few countries and the next checkbox "rest of the world" is the same like I had selected only "all countries" or also if I don't select any country and just "rest of the world"...

And connected to these questions, does it make a difference, in which way I do the settings? If I select for example "Germany", "France", and "rest of the world", will be different in Germany and France than in rest of the world?

Comment: Its divided because we can publish app to selected countries or all countries depending on our choice

Comment: There are many apps in Google Play that are available to only particular country

Comment: That's NOT what I mean, please read the (complete) post.

Answer (score 0):

> There's first "pricing" label. In the next line there's a checkbox
>   with "All Countries" and then a list with checkboxes for certain
>   contries.

This checkbox is used for distribute in the specific countries. In these case you have to checked every country where you want to distribute. It is very much useful if you want to distribute your app in less no of country.

Whereas in the second checkbox you no need to check where you don't want to publish your app. It is more useful if you want to distribute your app in whole world except one or two countries.

May be it is not useful for you that much but google and many people think that it is more useful.(Specially the app made for some specific group of people.)